# iPad - Daylight Saving Conversion

Tags: ios, nsdate, nsdateformatter, dst

I'm facing an issue, I have NSString that I want to convert to NSDate, region on my device is set to New York so when daylight saving is active my app misbehaves,

Like e.g: **03/08/2015 02:00 - 03/08/2015 02:59**

Whenever the user selects this date-range the datepicker moves it an hour into the future which it should as daylight saving is active but I want my app to be able to pick/select this date-range because in some other region some other user is using the app at this date-range & doing some transaction so how can I my app to handle daylight saving.

Above scenario happens if user picks the date-range from NSDatePicker or If I try to create that date-range using NSDate & NSDateFormatter.

Thanks.

Comment: This date range simply does not exist in your time zone. If you are in a US timezone the difference between 03/08/2015 1:59 and 03/08/2015 3:00 is only one minute. If you select that range it is a minute in all other time zones as well. Doesn't matter that it looks like it is an hour and a minute in your timezone. Don't confuse the point in time at your location (where 2:00 does not exist), with the point in time.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch so you are saying I cant create a Timestamp for this range? Can you tell any function or property in NSDatePicker that can tell me if daylight is active for my region?

Comment: Relevant: [the DST tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info)

Answer (score 1):

You asked about [`NSDatePicker`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSDatePicker_Class/), but I believe that is for OSX.  The datepicker class in iOS is [`UIDatePicker`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDatePicker_Class/).  At least, this is how it appears from the documentation.

Both of these classes have a `timeZone` property, which you can set to any valid `NSTimeZone` instance.  When not set explicitly, the default behavior is to use the *local* time zone.

So if you want to pick a time in another time zone, with different DST rules, then just set the time zone accordingly.  You might consider using the UTC time zone if you want to be able to accept all values.